# How do we determine the slope for leakyrelu activation function?

Tags: pytorch, activation-functions, leaky-relu

I am using `LeakyReLU` activation function in my architecture. We know that the default slope value is `1e-2`. I want to understand how do we decide that what slope value should we choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely no 'mathematically optimal' LeakyReLU value, as it is dependent on the data, the architecture etc.

In addition, to the best of my knowledge, there is no 'best practice' when it comes to LeakyReLU slope values. Most of the deep learning papers just state they use LeakyReLU with some slope parameter without mentioning why they choose the parameter. They might, or even might not, have tuned the parameter with simple empirical testing.

The goal of LeakyRelu is simply to reduce the 'dying relu' problem. As long as there is *any* slope, this dying relu problem is mitigated. You could probably show that the dying relu problem persists by slope values very close to 0. With a default of 0.02, 0.01 or anything relatively significant, leaky relu does the job it is meant to do. I have seen LeakyRelu slopes up to 0.2-0.3 in GAN literature.

Do not expect a small difference in LeakyReLU values to drastically influence the result of your network. It might help a tiny bit during tuning, but I'd recommend starting with the default value and then continuing with the rest of your model training. Come back to tuning the LeakyRelu only during the final model optimization and see if you can make any significant difference by wiggling the value around the default value.

Comment: Thanks for the description!

Comment: Thanks for selecting my answer as the correct one. In addition, it is always helpful for future visitors to also upvote the correct answer to show that it was helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

When this slope in the negative part is learned, the activation function is called Parametric ReLU or PReLU.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PReLU.html